# How to Fix the Code In Order to lets the Function Working

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I'm getting a django project to fix the error inside the code, may I know what is the problem of this few line of code which cause the add and delete button on the webpage does not function well?

I've tried fixing some typo error in the code, but it's still not working so I'm changing back the code to it's original way.

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        var i=1;
        $("#add_row").click(function(){
            $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input 
                name='item_id' type='item_id' placeholder='Item ID' 
                class='form-control input-md'   /> </td><td><input  
                name='item_name' type='text' placeholder='Item Name'  
                class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  
                name='description' type='text' placeholder='Description'  
                class='form-control input-md' ></td><td><input name='quantity' 
                type='text' placeholder='Quantity' class='form-control input- 
                md'  /> </td><td><input name='unit_price' type='text' 
                placeholder='Price Per Unit' class='form-control input-md'  /> 
                </td>");

                $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
                i++; 

            });

        $("#delete_row").click(function(){
            if(i>1){
                $('#addr'+(i-1)).html('');
                i--;
            }
        });

    });
</script>

<div class="formpurchaseorder margintop" >

    <form class="purchaseordersubmission" 
          action="purchaserequisitionconfirmation" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row margintop">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="purchase_requisition_id" value="{{purchase_requisition_id}}"  placeholder="Purchase Requisition ID" readonly>
            </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="person_id" id="person_id" value="{{person_id}}"placeholder="Person ID" readonly>
    </div>

        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">

                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th class="text-center">#</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Item ID</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Item Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Description</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Price Per Unit</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody name="item_rows">
                        <tr id='addr'>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td> <input type="text" name='item_id' placeholder='Item id'  class="form-control" /> </td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="item_name"  placeholder='Item name' class="form-control" ></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name='description' placeholder='Description' class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name='quantity' placeholder='Quantity'  class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name='unit_price' placeholder='Price Per Unit'  class="form-control"  /></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr id='addr1'></tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a id='add_row' class="pull-left btn btn-default">Add Item</a>
        <a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Item</a>

        <div class="margintop">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-square buttonsize">Submit</button>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-square buttonsize" href="/menu">Cancel</a>
        </div>


    </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *does not function well*? Please add the error you are getting or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using stackblitz or jsfiddle.

Comment: the add and delete button on the web page is not functioning

Answer (score 0):

looks like your script is loaded before the HTML fully rendered and perhaps jQuery. 
Try to put this script section at the end of your `<body>` *(eventually in app/layout.html)*. 
After the jQuery implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Variables like `item_id` will only be available to you when you submit the form and then you'll be redirected to a URL with all the variables posted on it.

Eg. `localhost:8000/index.html?item_id=xyz&item_name=abc&description=desc&quantity=12&unit_price=30`

Notice the variable name with their values in the URL. This will only be available after you submit the form.

So Instead of adding the event listener on `add_row`, use :

```
$('#formid').submit(function(e) {
// Add the rows here
});
```

PS:- If you really want to do it this way, then you can get the text box values by :

First giving an ID to the input text box :

`<input type="text" id='item_name_textbox' name='item_id' placeholder='Item id'  class="form-control" /> </td>`

`var item_name = document.getElementById('item_name_textbox').value;`

and then using it in your function.